# How to make a dynamic baseURL in axios

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, nuxtjs

Let's say that i have `baseURL` defined inside a given service as follows :

```
import axios from 'axios'

const myAPI = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://api.domaine.com/',
  withCredentials: false,
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
})

export default {

  getUsers(){
     MyAPI.get('/users?order=desc&sort=name');
   },

  getUser(id){
      MyAPI.get('/users/'+id+'?order=desc&sort=name');

  }
....
 

}
```

In this example `?order=desc&sort=name` is repeated for each request how can add it to baseURL and make it dynamic like :

```
 baseURL: 'https://api.domaine.com/%s?order=desc&sort=name',
```

where `%s` could be replaced by `'/users/'+id` or  `'/users/'`, it's possible like this or there's any other way to parse the URL to make it dynamic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use params field, i.e.:

```
const myAPI = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://api.domaine.com/',
  withCredentials: false,
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  params: {
    order: 'desc',
    sort: 'name'
  }
})
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kquvw0jy/  (check console network tab to see request)

Comment: Thanks, i tried it out but the params are not append to the URL

Comment: There is an open issue for some versions of Axios. Try to use v0.18.1 or wait for v0.20.0 You can check it here: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/2190

Comment: @KarinC i think i should downgrade the axios version to v0.18.1

Comment: Hello BoussadjraBrahim, sorry about that. I used preexisting fiddle with added axios, and copied your snippet there. The version of axios in the fiddle is (0.16.2) https://unpkg.com/axios@0.16.2/dist/axios.js . I wasn't aware of the issue mentioned above. @KarinC appreciate your help, thank you!